# Plotting Pareto frontier with matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, optimization, genetic-algorithm

Showing two objectives with the non-dominated solutions, I can plot the scatter figure to illustrate it.

Here is my example utilizing different colors to display the solution set:

[image]

But I have read about this [github repository](https://github.com/matthewjwoodruff/pareto.py), its visualization method is quite good with grids to reach the best solution like this: 
[image]

But there are not any referencing code on plotting this figure. I have already tried to rebuild that but fail.

Any advices or referencing is appreciate!

Comment: The code for plotting above result can be found on the github [here](https://github.com/matthewjwoodruff/pareto.py/blob/picture/picture.py)

Comment: Advice: know whether smaller is better or big is better.  For the upper plot the higher numbers are better but for the lower one, the smaller values make the frontier.